# How do I send a Success message to user when account is created successfully in Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am creating an application that requires a simple user registration form. I am using account:core package to create users but my challenge is that the user gets created without any form of reply to the user that the account was successfully created. Here is my code

```
    Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Accounts.createUser({
            email: $('[name=email]').val(),
            password: $('[name=password]').val(),
            profile: {
                first_name: $('[name=firstname]').val(),
                last_name: $('[name=lastname]').val(),
                current_location: $('[name=currentlocation]').val(),
                date: $('[name=date]').val(),
                phone_number: $('[name=phonenumber]').val(),
            }
        });
    },

});
```

Comment: How do I also send back error of duplicate email to user?

Answer (score 1):

`Accounts.createUser(options, [callback])` accepts a callback as the second parameter, which gets called once the account creation is completed. In this callback you can post your message to the user.
See the docs for more [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser).